# How to keep / lock USB in place

Tags: laptop, usb

My old(ish) macbook has run out of storage, so I bought an external USB drive. I have installed mac OSX onto it and it is now my main boot drive. I fear the drive USB may come out occasionally given that the macbook is a portable device. Is there anything which can physically keep / lock the USB in place to eliminate this threat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try what's described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_ruqSrkxNU) video.

Basically what he does is bend the "retention pins" inside the female end of the USB port so that the male plug is held in more firmly.

I'm not sure if your "USB drive" is a "stick" that just plugs in, or a short cable with a portable HDD on the end.

If it is a portable hard drive with a cable, (see image) you could do what user NZKshatriya suggested in [a previous question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6523/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-schleptop-small-portable-desktop-ish/6527#6527) and "*just use double sided tape or velcro, and attach them to the lid of the laptop*.".

So in conclusion, the two best options I think you have are:

- Bend the (possibly loose) USB "retention pins" on the female USB plug
- "just use double sided tape or velcro, and attach them to the lid of the laptop" (assuming that it is a portable hard drive)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the USB ports do not have the same retention pins and cannot be adjusted. I am using a cable so I think my best bet is probably to use sticky tape or velcro. Thanks for your help.